# why does HTML require double click when it first loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does my HTML require my button, to show my radio buttons, to be double clicked when I first load the page but its only single click to toggle the form from showing and hiding afterwards. Cant seem to figure it out. 
Here is my js function

```
function madison() {
var x = document.getElementById("madison_inv");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

Here is my HTML. Just trying to get the "Madison" button to work for now. It loads the form perfectly fine and runs my php and such. Just requires a double click when I first load the page, but I want it to be a simple single click.

```
    <div class="navbar">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Campus Locations
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <button onclick="main_hosp()"  class="button" id="huntsville">Huntsville Hospital</button>
    <button onclick="wc_hosp()" class="button" id="wc">Womens and Childrens Hospital</button>
    <button onclick="madison()" class="button" id="madison">Madison Hospital</button>
</div>      
</div>
</div><br>

    <form id="madison_inv"><strong> View Report for:</strong>
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="Total Inv Count" onclick="mad_totinv()">Total Inventory Count</input>
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="Total Narc Count" onclick="mad_totNarc()">Total Narc Count</input>
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="Pyxis Inv Count" onclick="mad_pyxisinv()">Pyxis Inventory Count</input>
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="Pyxis Narc Count" onclick="mad_pyxisnarc()">Pyxis Narc Count</input>
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="Pyxis NonNarc Count" onclick="mad_pyxisnonnarc()">Pyxis NonNarc Count</input>
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="Vault Count" onclick="mad_vault()">Vault Count</input>
            </form> <br>

</article>
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/0os67dxn/). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Note that the radio buttons start out showing, not hidden; your opening sentence seems to suggest they start out hidden.

Comment: I  have it hidden using CSS when it first loads. #madison_inv {

display:none;

}

Comment: FYI, you're `<article>` tag is missing, only `</article>` appears and is unmatched

Comment: the article tag is there just didnt copy up that far.

Answer (score 1):

Your quoted code works provided the buttons start out visible, but your question suggests they don't; if you're hiding them with a CSS rule you haven't shown us *(edit: [you've confirmed now that you are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392855/why-does-html-require-double-click-when-it-first-loads/50393044#comment87801758_50392855))*, then the problem is that `display` will be `""` initially (even though they're hidden with CSS), so this logic:

```
var x = document.getElementById("madison_inv");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

...hides on first click. After the first click, it'll toggle.

To get the value of `display` allowing for CSS, you don't use `.style`, you use `getComputedStyle` (falling back to `currentStyle` for obsolete IE). In your page setup:

```
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
    // Fallback for obsolete IE
    window.getComputedStyle = function(e) {
        return e.currentStyle;
    };
}
```

then

```
var x = document.getElementById("madison_inv");
if (getComputedStyle(x).display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

Example:

```js
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
    // Fallback for obsolete IE
    window.getComputedStyle = function(e) {
        return e.currentStyle;
    };
}

function madison() {
    var x = document.getElementById("madison_inv");
    if (getComputedStyle(x).display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
#madison_inv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="madison()">Madison</button>
<div id="madison_inv">Radio buttons here</div>
```

**However**, I would recommend toggling a class instead:

```js
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
    // Fallback for obsolete IE
    window.getComputedStyle = function(e) {
        return e.currentStyle;
    };
}

function madison() {
    var x = document.getElementById("madison_inv");
    x.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
#madison_inv {
  /* ...any other styles for it...*/
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="madison()">Madison</button>
<div id="madison_inv" class="hidden">Radio buttons here</div>
```

Comment: Ahh. Ok let me make some adjustments quick. Thank you.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: Changed it to a toggle a class. Thanks a lot. I